# IRSSI: Disable bell on activity in certain channel

Tags: notifications, irc, irssi, bell

I use **IRSSI** (*Win 8.1 x64* + *cygwin* + *SSH* to remote host, sometimes via *putty* instead of cygwin) and it's configured to flash taskbar button whenever there's activity in any channel or private chat.

There's a bot in one of the channels I'm in which frequently sends some information to the channel and I don't want to be notified about that. Using ignore on this bot isn't helpful because ignored lines don't get printed in the channel or save to the logs - and I still need that info.

Is it possible to disable bell/taskbar flashing ONLY for a certain channel or a single user in that channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of **irssi 0.8.17** it's possible to ignore ONLY activity:

```
/help ignore
```

> The special level 'NO_ACT' can be used to ignore activity in the statusbar
>   without actually ignoring the message; this behavior is somewhat special 
>   because it is allowed in addition to other ignores for the same target.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> /IGNORE mike NO_ACT -MSGS
> ```